# Duplicate elements in array based on values from second array, using jq

Tags: jq

In `jq`, I would like to duplicate elements n-times in the first array based on the values of the second array. As seen in the example below, I would like to have the first element of the first array two times and the second element of the array three times. The number of elements is different in each case.

```json
["1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif"]
["2", "3"]
```

The desired output should look like this:

```json
["1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif", "1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif"]
```

I tried some things but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's ok to pass the input to `jq` as JSON fragments using the `--argjson` option:

```
jq -n \
    --argjson reps '["2","3"]' \
    --argjson strs '["1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif"]' \
    '[ $reps | keys[] as $i | [range($reps[$i]|tonumber)] | map($strs[$i]) ] | flatten'
```

Output:

```json
[
  "1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif",
  "1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif",
  "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif",
  "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif",
  "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif"
]
```

The code assumes that the two arrays, `$reps` and `$strs`, are of the same length and uses `$reps` to set up a loop with the loop variable `$i` iterating over the indexes of the arrays.

The statements

```
[range($reps[$i]|tonumber)] | map($strs[$i])
```

... creates an array that is as long as the `$i`:th number in `$reps` and then replaces each of the entries in that array with the corresponding string from `$strs`. This effectively duplicates the `$i`:th string in `$strs` as many times as the `$i`:th number in `$reps`.

The `$i` loop happens inside an array construction (`[ ...here... ] | flatten`) and will, with the data in the question create a single array containing *two* subarrays of strings.  The `flatten` filter "flattens" these arrays into a single array of strings, which is our end product.

For compact output, use `jq` with its `-c` option.

If the array containing the repetitions contains *numbers* instead of strings, i.e. something like `[2,3]` instead of `["2","3"]`, then you may remove the `tonumber` conversion filter from the expression.